# Magnetic field intensity H and Magnetic field density B

Tags: magnetic-fields

> Standards Organizations have recently moved to magnetic constant as
>   the preferred name for μ0, although the older name continues to be
>   listed as a synonym. Historically, the constant μ0 has had
>   different names. In the 1987 IUPAP Red book, for example, this
>   constant was still called permeability of vacuum. Another, now
>   rather rare and obsolete, term is "magnetic permittivity of vacuum".
>   See, for example, Servant et al. The term "vacuum permeability"
>   (and variations thereof, such as "permeability of free space") remains
>   very widespread.
>
> The name "magnetic constant" was used by standards organizations in
>   order to avoid use of the terms "permeability" and "vacuum", which
>   have physical meanings. This change of preferred name had been made
>   because μ0 was a defined value, **and was not the result of experimental
>   measurement (see below).** In the new SI system, the permeability of
>   vacuum will not be a constant anymore, but a measured quantity,
>   related to the (measured) dimensionless fine structure constant.

How did we arrive to the value of vaccum permiability μ₀? I mean if we consider the formula B=μ₀H it means that B is the μ₀ (some constant) times H, so B inside material/vaccum can be calculated by multiplying μ₀/μ with H but how will we calculate H then? My confusion is that is there any situation where B=H? If it isn't there then how come B=μ₀H for vaccum?

Comment: $B$ and $H$ are not always proportional. $H$ also depends on magnetisation. Altough it can be experimentally found the other way round, $\vec{B}$ is more fundamental, and it is given by the laws of Biot-Savart, Lorentz, Ampère, and so on. Then we define $\vec{H}$ because it can be more useful, just like we do with $\vec{D}$ for $\vec{E}$

Comment: But we know that B will be different for different materials for same H due to different μ . My confusion is that how did we arrived at the value of μ₀ .? If H is the magnetic field in free space and B is in material then B=μH makes sense as in the material it can be more /less but for vaccum it shoul be 1,isn't it?

Comment: What is the source of the text in the image? Please don't cut and paste random stuff on the internet without attribution. It's rude. Also, please transcribe text that you want to quote rather than posting images. Using images breaks search functionality and doesn't work for blind people.

Comment: Sorry .. here is the source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability

Comment: You can build the entire electromagnetism without $H$, and $\mu_0$ still appears in many other formulae.

Comment: You will want to read this [page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability). In the SI system which is going into force in 2019, this value needs to be determined experimentally; 4π × 1.000 000 000 82 (20) 10−7 H·m−1 is a recently measured value in the new system.